# Fetching remote git repo and pushing latest branch to internal remote git repo

Tags: git

I am too new to Git, and stuck on something. What I want is :

- Fetch a large GitHub repository
- Checkout  a specific **tag** (a stable version in past) and delete all other information such as commit history, branches etc.
- Push the merged repository to the another Git repository in internal network

I tried to write something like below, but it doesn't work of course :)

```
git clone git://github.com/rmcardle/mRemoteNG.git
git checkout -b tags/1.69
git rebase -i
git remote add local http://myusername@myserver/scm/LIB/myrepo.git
git push local master
```

Answer (score 0):

After your `remote add` the repo, I think you have to `git add *` and `git commit -m "[type your message here]` then push the master. It'll be great if we can see `git status` .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git merge --squash` to squash all commits into one and then push it.

Comment: Do you mean instead of rebasing?

Comment: @noway I don't know what did you want to do in `rebase -i`